# Can we merge or switch the duplicate of the Crossbow Expert questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicates

[Crossbow Expert Feat... for Spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/117386/crossbow-expert-feat-for-spells) was marked correctly as a duplicate of [Does Crossbow Expert's point-blank attack benefit apply to all ranged attacks?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48173/does-crossbow-experts-point-blank-attack-benefit-apply-to-all-ranged-attacks).

However, the latter only has one positive answer which has only one sentence and no citations. The answers on the first question both have at least official support. (Full disclosure: one of them is mine if it matters at all.)

It seems to me that it would only be an improvement to switch around the duplicate marking in this case or to merge the Q&As.

Answer (score 7):

Good point. I've gone ahead and done it.

Answer (score 6):

As asker of the original question, I don't have a *strong* opinion, but I think mine is really the better dupe target as it covers non-spell, non-crossbow ranged attacks as well. If someone comes along later and asks about longbows or blowguns, that'd be a duplicate of mine but not of the new one, and if mine is closed as a dupe of the new one already, oops.

Comment: I thought about that like an hour after nitsua60 did this request, I think you have a point and I'm not sure how to balance that with the difference in quality of the answers between the two.

Comment: Moderator could do a merge, which would bring the other answers in. Or, we could nicely ask the people who answered the new question to bring their answers to the old one. Or we could add a bounty asking for canonical answers. So many possibilities. :)

Comment: Merging one question into another is possible. Will the answers to one question make sense as answers to the other? I imagine some revision will be needed to bring them in line. How much is needed, is it trivial or complex?

Comment: @doppelgreener In this case, they just need minor tweaks.

Comment: And if it merges newer into older, both I and Keith are active and (I'm assuming) willing to make the minor changes necessary if that's deemed the better option.